# Am I understanding "L" weight correctly?

Tags: starfinder

According to the Core Rulebook, an item of designation "L" can be thought of as being 1/10th of a bulk, as 10 of these items together counts as 1 bulk.  But then does that mean it is possible for my soldier to carry 10 cartridges (1 cartridge is 30 bullets and weights "L", for a total of 300 bullets!) and it only be 1 bulk?  Or that my character is able to carry 10 handguns and it only counts as 1 bulk?

Granted I know there is a degree of suspension of disbelief when playing games like this, but have you tried carrying 10 handguns or 300 bullets on your person?  No chance you can do that easily.  Am I missing a rule or is this correct?

Comment: Just as an interesting point, "Front Line" ammo carriage for an Australian rifleman in 2007 was 180 rounds. And this is long arm ammo, not small arm. And it's before adding any other gear. I've seen references to people carrying double frontline, as well as MG ammo.

Comment: Huh.  Details like the above are what make this site so helpful.  Thanks!  Do you have a reference for that or is it based on personal experience?

Comment: I googled it, and found a forum discussion, talking about wargames :) Several people chimed in, seeming to have military experience. I'll send you a link, if you like? It didn't really seem to have enough to warrant an entire answer.

Comment: Yeah, others might find the link helpful too.  Good find.

Comment: http://www.defencetalk.com/forums/army-security-forces/how-much-ammo-should-normal-infantryman-carry-5754/

Answer (score 6):

Carry ten magazines of thirty rounds each, in your hands?  No way.  Carry them on a bandolier or in an ammo bag?  No problem.  Likewise, try to carry ten handguns loose in your arms, and you'll drop them a lot -- but if they're boxed (as from the manufacturer), and the boxes are in a sturdy carton or bag, easy.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant that as 10 cartridges of 30 bullets, then it's 3 Bulk and you could walk around with them in your Backpacks... but probably not carry them unless they were otherwise boxed up.

The Backpack item indicates that it holds 2 Bulk of items, so you would need 2 Backpacks just to carry your cartridges, but there's nothing saying that's not possible. Alternately a backpack could hold about 20 well-placed handguns.

Poorly explained side-rules don't exempt you from a GM applying logic, and they do reference the GM's ability to apply logic to carrying equipment your equipment, but in reference to trying to carry hundreds of '-' weight items.